# Simple understanding of Sum symbol.

Tags: summation

I wonder if this is correct to write even if nj has unik length for each variable, so for x it can be 12, but for y it can be 20 and for z it can be 40.

[image]

Also is it possible to convert it to something like:

[image]

Comment: I think you are describing $\sum^{12}_{i=1}i+\sum^{20}_{i=1}i+\sum^{40}_{i=1}i$. This is not equivalent to $\sum^{n}_{1}(3i)$ since not all the $n$'s (upper bounds) in the previous summation were not equivalent ($12\neq20\neq40$).

You could write the above summation also as:
$$3\sum_{i=1}^{12}i+2\sum_{i=13}^{20}i+\sum_{i=21}^{40}i$$

Comment: @user2154420 Okey, what if the upper bonds are different, and the x,y and z are different how would you as easy as possible describe it?

Comment: I can't think of any simpler way to describe the summation. Are you looking for a particular form or do you need this for a specific application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sizes of x, y, and z are different, then you can't just use $n_j$ in this way - you'd need three different $n_j$'s (i.e. $n_j^1, n_j^2, n_j^3$).

And the notation of the double sum you have below is confusing, I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: If x,y,z are different, and the upper bonds are different and I want to sum first all the x's then the y's then the z's and then I want to sum the groups. how can I as easy as possible sum this?

Comment: I'd write it like so:

$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^J \left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_x}x_{ij} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_y}y_{ij} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_z}z_{ij} \right)
$

Assuming that they're all the same size in the j dimension, but can differ in the i dimension.